# How to group by id and show the min/max date properly

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How do I achieve the desired results from the sample table? I want to group by id, id2 and show the min start_date and max end_date. I have tried the following but is not giving me the desired results as shown in the last table.

```
SELECT
    id,
    id2,
    min(start_date),
    MAX(end_date)
    
  FROM
    table
  GROUP BY
    id,
    id2
```

sample table:

| id | id2 | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | a | 2022-11-05 | 2022-11-11 |
| abc | a | 2022-11-12 | 2022-11-18 |
| abc | b | 2022-12-03 | 2022-12-09 |
| abc | a | 2022-12-10 | 2022-12-16 |
| abc | a | 2022-12-17 | 2022-12-23 |

desired results:

| id | id2 | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | a | 2022-11-05 | 2022-11-18 |
| abc | b | 2022-12-03 | 2022-12-09 |
| abc | a | 2022-12-10 | 2022-12-23 |

my attempt:

| id | id2 | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | a | 2022-11-05 | 2022-12-23 |
| abc | b | 2022-12-03 | 2022-12-09 |

Comment: Changed the wording.. hopefully that makes more sense haha (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider below `gaps and islands` approach.

```sql
-- your sample data
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 'abc' id, 'a' id2, '2022-11-05' start_date, '2022-11-11' end_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc' id, 'a' id2, '2022-11-12' start_date, '2022-11-18' end_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc' id, 'b' id2, '2022-12-03' start_date, '2022-12-09' end_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc' id, 'a' id2, '2022-12-10' start_date, '2022-12-16' end_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc' id, 'a' id2, '2022-12-17' start_date, '2022-12-23' end_date
)
-- query starts here
SELECT id, id2, MIN(start_date) start_date, MAX(end_date) end_date 
  FROM (
    SELECT *, COUNT(1) OVER w0 - COUNT(1) OVER w1 AS grp 
      FROM sample_table
    WINDOW w0 AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_date),
           w1 AS (PARTITION BY id, id2 ORDER BY start_date)
  )
 GROUP BY id, id2, grp ORDER BY start_date;

-- query result
+-----+-----+------------+------------+
| id  | id2 | start_date |  end_date  |
+-----+-----+------------+------------+
| abc | a   | 2022-11-05 | 2022-11-18 |
| abc | b   | 2022-12-03 | 2022-12-09 |
| abc | a   | 2022-12-10 | 2022-12-23 |
+-----+-----+------------+------------+
```